# Vision - text Recognize

Tags: ios, swift, vision

I've been struggling with this problem for some time.
I want to use the Vision framework to recognize the text from the photo.

Everything works. The recognized text is passed to the text view etc.
additional - I added a bounding Box that can be seen in the picture

example

[image]

The next step that he wants to perform is the recognized element ex from the tex "CRU007" and pass it on

I do not know how to do this

this is my code:

```
   func setupVision() {
    guard let image = UIImage(named: "example.card.04" ) else {return}
    
    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let scaledHeight = view.frame.width / image.size.width * image.size.height
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: scaledHeight)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {return}
    
    let myRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
    
    let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
        
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {return}
        
        for visionResult in results {
            let maximumCandidate = 1
            guard let candidate = visionResult.topCandidates(maximumCandidate).first else {
                continue
            }
            
            self.textView.text += candidate.string
            self.textView.text += "\n"
            

            
            if let range = candidate.string.range(of: "CRU007") {
                let boxObservation = try? candidate.boundingBox(for: range)
                
                print(boxObservation?.boundingBox)

                let x = self.view.frame.width * visionResult.boundingBox.origin.x
                let height = scaledHeight * visionResult.boundingBox.height
                let y = scaledHeight * ( 1 - visionResult.boundingBox.origin.y) - height
                let widht = self.view.frame.width * visionResult.boundingBox.width

                let greenView = UIView()
                greenView.layer.borderWidth = 3
                greenView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                greenView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: widht, height: height)
                self.view.addSubview(greenView)
            }
        }
    }
    request.recognitionLevel = .accurate
    try? myRequestHandler.perform([request])
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this means: "The next step that he wants to perform is the recognized element ex from the tex "CRU007" and pass it on" Could you rephrase that?

Comment: @Rethunk the selected text in the green frame contains the number of the card that I want to pass it to the API call.
The problem is that the scanned text is a string.
example
"M. CRU007 Alexander Mokhov © 2020 Legend Story Studios"

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what's needed here. Please edit your original post to include a specific question, and to summarize what you've tried. (Thanks for providing code, but it'd help to have some more context.) It's unclear to me whether you want some kind of regular expression to extract the card number, or some algorithm to distinguish a card number from the rest of the text. If there's some sort of pattern or syntax to card names, please provide that--for example, a card ID might always be three alphabetical characters followed by three numeric characters.